# RestAssured - How to read an array element from the json response

Tags: java, json, api, get, rest-assured

```
    @Test
public void getFirstRequestVerifyResponse()
{
String idToValidate= "5ea6fe53e4b09a8de7aeb19d";
    System.out.println("Response :" + response.asString());
    System.out.println("id : " + response.asString().contains(idToValidate));

}
```

I am getting the following response.

```
Response :[{"id":"5ea6fe53e4b09a8de7aeb19d","contents":[{"pageSize":6,"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1538998610009"}],"name":"FEATURE BANNER","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","showAll":false,"autoCarousel":false,"ty":"BANNER","action":{"source":"BE","contentId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1538998610009","t":"Play","st":"PLAY"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}}}},{"id":"5ac37644e4b03f23a4a705dc","contents":[],"name":"MastheadAd","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","ty":"NATIVE_MASTHEAD_AD","action":{"source":"BE","st":"CUSTOM","sTy":"CUSTOM_AMAZON"},"contentAction":{"sTy":"CUSTOM_AMAZON","meta":{}},"lds":[],"adId":"/417241724/tv_native_masthead_plain_prod","tId":["11767767","11768950"]}},{"id":"5d63ca1de4b088013a6236b3","contents":[{"pageSize":50,"source":"RM","packageId":"dummy"}],"name":"Recommended Movies","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","showAll":false,"ty":"MOVIE_NOLOGO","contentAction":{"meta":{"sourceName":"cf_movies_home"}}}},{"id":"5d63ca1de4b088013a6236b2","contents":[{"pageSize":50,"source":"RM","packageId":"dummy"}],"name":"Recommended TV Shows","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","showAll":false,"ty":"MOVIE_NOLOGO","contentAction":{"meta":{"sourceName":"cf_tvshow_home"}}}},{"id":"5ae6b962e4b088c1fe893389","contents":[{"pageSize":20,"source":"MW","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1524207345077","ty":"LIVE"}],"name":"LIVE NEWS","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","showAll":false,"bgImgUrl":"","ty":"TVSHOW_LOGO_43","action":{"color":"#ff0000","pageId":"live_TV","t":"More","st":"LANDING"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"t":"LIVE NEWS"}},{"id":"5e74bffce4b0e60befa24bbb","contents":[{"pageSize":10,"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1568185919253"}],"name":"Your Daily News in 30 Secs HIndi","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","showAll":false,"bgImgUrl":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5d2d6945e4b06e55de6b8cfe/editorji_highlightrail_background.jpg","ty":"TVSHOW_BIG_43","action":{"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1568185919253","listingType":"TVSHOW_BIG_43","t":"More","st":"LISTING"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"t":"Your Daily News in 30 Secs"}},{"id":"5d9ec624e4b0499e024c99c6","contents":[{"pageSize":10,"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1570605272423"}],"name":"Learn with Xstream","format":{"lsTy":"EXPLORE","ty":"CUSTOM","action":{"st":"DEFAULT"},"contentAction":{"source":"BE","pageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1570605272423","st":"CUSTOM","sTy":"LISTING","meta":{}},"lds":[],"t":"Learn with Xstream"}},{"id":"5c78ce19e4b0d4a057339b17","contents":[{"pageSize":25,"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1540027201907"}],"name":"MOST WATCHED HOLLYWOOD MOVIES","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","showAll":false,"ty":"MOVIE_NOLOGO","action":{"color":"#a1ec00","source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1540027201907","listingType":"MOVIE_NOLOGO","t":"More","st":"LISTING"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"t":"Most Watched Hollywood Movies"}},{"id":"5e789319e4b032c54a8f0646","contents":[],"name":"Family Movie Card - English + Hindi","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","ty":"CARD_NOTITILE_169","action":{"source":"MW","channelId":"MWTV_LIVETVCHANNEL_10000000060880000","t":"Play","st":"PLAY","meta":{"k":"1"},"ty":"LIVE"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"lds":[],"img":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5e9083e8e4b0cff1aeeb2d58/Swami_Ramdev_New.jpg"}},{"id":"5d64b170e4b067b667714913","contents":[{"pageSize":12,"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1566817268865"}],"name":"BEST HOLLYWOOD Series","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","showAll":false,"ty":"MOVIE_NOLOGO","action":{"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1566817268865","listingType":"MOVIE_NOLOGO","t":"More","st":"LISTING"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"t":"Best Hollywood Movie Series"}},{"id":"5e7892e6e4b032c54a8f0645","contents":[],"name":"Nostalgia Movie Card - English + Hindi","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","ty":"CARD_NOTITILE_169","hIcon":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5e7892e6e4b032c54a8f0645/ic_cplogo_hooq.png","action":{"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1584939335512","listingType":"MOVIE_NOLOGO","t":"More","st":"LISTING","meta":{"A":"1"}},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"lds":[],"img":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5e7892e6e4b032c54a8f0645/NOSTALGIA-MOVIES-1032X576_(1).jpg"}},{"id":"5e99b557e4b0c3a92edf1ee7","contents":[],"name":"Wynk Music - Vishal Mishra - Live Concert Card Testing","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","ty":"CARD_NOTITILE_169","action":{"source":"BE","contentId":"MWTV_LIVETVCHANNEL_10000000060880000","t":"Play","st":"PLAY","meta":{"k":"1"}},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"lds":[],"img":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5e99b010e4b03c81436668d3/1-Lohri-1032X576.jpg"}},{"id":"5ea70c25e4b0cea120315672","contents":[],"name":"Astha Gill Type Form Card Test","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","ty":"PRODUCT_CARD","action":{"url":"https://wynkproduct.typeform.com/to/DesNW4","t":"Play","st":"WEBVIEW","meta":{"redirectType":"REDIRECT_TV","redirectDeeplink":"https://wynkproduct.typeform.com/to/DesNW4"}},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"lds":[],"img":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5ea70c25e4b0cea120315672/2-Badla-1032X576_(1).jpg"}},{"id":"5ea711a0e4b0cea120315674","contents":[],"name":"Aastha Gill - Card - Test","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","ty":"CARD_NOTITILE_169","action":{"source":"MW","channelId":"MWTV_LIVETVCHANNEL_10000000060880000","t":"Play","st":"PLAY","ty":"LIVE"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"lds":[],"img":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5ea711a0e4b0cea120315674/2-Badla-1032X576_(1).jpg"}},{"id":"5ea70fcfe4b0cea120315673","contents":[],"name":"test_card_ndtv","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","ty":"CARD_NOTITILE_169","action":{"source":"MW","channelId":"MWTV_LIVETVCHANNEL_10000000060880000","t":"NDTV","st":"PLAY","ty":"LIVE"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"lt":"","ds":"","lds":[],"img":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5ea70fcfe4b0cea120315673/photo-1549465220-1a8b9238cd48.jpeg"}}]
```

How can I get the "packageId" from the response for this idToValidate. Please help me on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JsonPath

```
String res = "Response :[{"id":"5ea6fe53e4b09a8de7aeb19d","contents":[{"pageSize":6,"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1538998610009"}],"name":"FEATURE BANNER","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","showAll":false,"autoCarousel":false,"ty":"BANNER","action":{"source":"BE","contentId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1538998610009","t":"Play","st":"PLAY"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}}}},{"id":"5ac37644e4b03f23a4a705dc","contents":[],"name":"MastheadAd","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","ty":"NATIVE_MASTHEAD_AD","action":{"source":"BE","st":"CUSTOM","sTy":"CUSTOM_AMAZON"},"contentAction":{"sTy":"CUSTOM_AMAZON","meta":{}},"lds":[],"adId":"/417241724/tv_native_masthead_plain_prod","tId":["11767767","11768950"]}},{"id":"5d63ca1de4b088013a6236b3","contents":[{"pageSize":50,"source":"RM","packageId":"dummy"}],"name":"Recommended Movies","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","showAll":false,"ty":"MOVIE_NOLOGO","contentAction":{"meta":{"sourceName":"cf_movies_home"}}}},{"id":"5d63ca1de4b088013a6236b2","contents":[{"pageSize":50,"source":"RM","packageId":"dummy"}],"name":"Recommended TV Shows","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","showAll":false,"ty":"MOVIE_NOLOGO","contentAction":{"meta":{"sourceName":"cf_tvshow_home"}}}},{"id":"5ae6b962e4b088c1fe893389","contents":[{"pageSize":20,"source":"MW","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1524207345077","ty":"LIVE"}],"name":"LIVE NEWS","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","showAll":false,"bgImgUrl":"","ty":"TVSHOW_LOGO_43","action":{"color":"#ff0000","pageId":"live_TV","t":"More","st":"LANDING"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"t":"LIVE NEWS"}},{"id":"5e74bffce4b0e60befa24bbb","contents":[{"pageSize":10,"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1568185919253"}],"name":"Your Daily News in 30 Secs HIndi","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","showAll":false,"bgImgUrl":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5d2d6945e4b06e55de6b8cfe/editorji_highlightrail_background.jpg","ty":"TVSHOW_BIG_43","action":{"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1568185919253","listingType":"TVSHOW_BIG_43","t":"More","st":"LISTING"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"t":"Your Daily News in 30 Secs"}},{"id":"5d9ec624e4b0499e024c99c6","contents":[{"pageSize":10,"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1570605272423"}],"name":"Learn with Xstream","format":{"lsTy":"EXPLORE","ty":"CUSTOM","action":{"st":"DEFAULT"},"contentAction":{"source":"BE","pageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1570605272423","st":"CUSTOM","sTy":"LISTING","meta":{}},"lds":[],"t":"Learn with Xstream"}},{"id":"5c78ce19e4b0d4a057339b17","contents":[{"pageSize":25,"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1540027201907"}],"name":"MOST WATCHED HOLLYWOOD MOVIES","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","showAll":false,"ty":"MOVIE_NOLOGO","action":{"color":"#a1ec00","source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1540027201907","listingType":"MOVIE_NOLOGO","t":"More","st":"LISTING"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"t":"Most Watched Hollywood Movies"}},{"id":"5e789319e4b032c54a8f0646","contents":[],"name":"Family Movie Card - English + Hindi","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","ty":"CARD_NOTITILE_169","action":{"source":"MW","channelId":"MWTV_LIVETVCHANNEL_10000000060880000","t":"Play","st":"PLAY","meta":{"k":"1"},"ty":"LIVE"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"lds":[],"img":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5e9083e8e4b0cff1aeeb2d58/Swami_Ramdev_New.jpg"}},{"id":"5d64b170e4b067b667714913","contents":[{"pageSize":12,"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1566817268865"}],"name":"BEST HOLLYWOOD Series","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","showAll":false,"ty":"MOVIE_NOLOGO","action":{"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1566817268865","listingType":"MOVIE_NOLOGO","t":"More","st":"LISTING"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"t":"Best Hollywood Movie Series"}},{"id":"5e7892e6e4b032c54a8f0645","contents":[],"name":"Nostalgia Movie Card - English + Hindi","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","ty":"CARD_NOTITILE_169","hIcon":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5e7892e6e4b032c54a8f0645/ic_cplogo_hooq.png","action":{"source":"BE","packageId":"ATV_PACKAGE_1584939335512","listingType":"MOVIE_NOLOGO","t":"More","st":"LISTING","meta":{"A":"1"}},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"lds":[],"img":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5e7892e6e4b032c54a8f0645/NOSTALGIA-MOVIES-1032X576_(1).jpg"}},{"id":"5e99b557e4b0c3a92edf1ee7","contents":[],"name":"Wynk Music - Vishal Mishra - Live Concert Card Testing","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","ty":"CARD_NOTITILE_169","action":{"source":"BE","contentId":"MWTV_LIVETVCHANNEL_10000000060880000","t":"Play","st":"PLAY","meta":{"k":"1"}},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"lds":[],"img":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5e99b010e4b03c81436668d3/1-Lohri-1032X576.jpg"}},{"id":"5ea70c25e4b0cea120315672","contents":[],"name":"Astha Gill Type Form Card Test","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","ty":"PRODUCT_CARD","action":{"url":"https://wynkproduct.typeform.com/to/DesNW4","t":"Play","st":"WEBVIEW","meta":{"redirectType":"REDIRECT_TV","redirectDeeplink":"https://wynkproduct.typeform.com/to/DesNW4"}},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"lds":[],"img":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5ea70c25e4b0cea120315672/2-Badla-1032X576_(1).jpg"}},{"id":"5ea711a0e4b0cea120315674","contents":[],"name":"Aastha Gill - Card - Test","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","ty":"CARD_NOTITILE_169","action":{"source":"MW","channelId":"MWTV_LIVETVCHANNEL_10000000060880000","t":"Play","st":"PLAY","ty":"LIVE"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"lds":[],"img":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5ea711a0e4b0cea120315674/2-Badla-1032X576_(1).jpg"}},{"id":"5ea70fcfe4b0cea120315673","contents":[],"name":"test_card_ndtv","format":{"lsTy":"DEFAULT","ty":"CARD_NOTITILE_169","action":{"source":"MW","channelId":"MWTV_LIVETVCHANNEL_10000000060880000","t":"NDTV","st":"PLAY","ty":"LIVE"},"contentAction":{"meta":{}},"lt":"","ds":"","lds":[],"img":"https://image.airtel.tv/pages/rails/5ea70fcfe4b0cea120315673/photo-1549465220-1a8b9238cd48.jpeg"}}]";
```

**Code :**

```
    JsonPath js = new JsonPath(res);
    String idToValidate = "5ae6b962e4b088c1fe893389";
    System.out.println("id : " + res.contains(idToValidate));

    String packageId = js.get("find {it.id =='"+idToValidate+"'}.contents.packageId").toString();
    System.out.println("PackageID : " + packageId);
```

**Output :**

> ID : true
>
> PackageID : [ATV_PACKAGE_1524207345077]

**Alternative :**

```
String output = given().when().get(url).then().extract().body().jsonPath().get("find {it.id =='"+idToValidate+"'}.contents.packageId").toString();
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: Instead of concatenating the string, you could use `params` in JSON Path

Comment: @Fenio I wasn't very sure of your statement but I've updated the ans with an alternative way which I think is same as your statement

Comment: @WilfredClement Something like this: `js.param("idToValidate", idToValidate).get("find {it.id == idToValidate}.contents.packageId").toString();` There is no String concatenation. More readable and easier to maintain. But your solution works as intended so +1 :)